# Variable Scope in Google Maps API and Angular 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

So I have a Google Maps API event listener for on click the map.  But I don't think the variable scope is working.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {

    $scope.closeBox();

});

$scope.closeBox = function () {

    $scope.showBox = false;

}
```

If I have $scope.showBox = true on the map and click the map it doesn't close.  $scope.showBox is an ng-class that shows/hides the information box.

Comment: Did you try to debug $scope inside your callback function? Listeners may run with a different context from where they are declared. I would try to work around that with a specific context. What if you try: google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', $scope.closeBox.bind(this));

Comment: That didn't work but I just added a $scope.$apply() call and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I just added a $scope.$apply() call and it worked